# Will Aura Continue to be Supported in the Medium/Long Term

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

According to this article https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/02/working-with-aura-and-lightning-web-components-interoperability-and-migration.html, LWC is clearly preferred over Aura.

> For the most part, if you’re building brand new functionality, you should look at building with Lightning web components first.

This is perfectly understandable due to its many advantages.

Can this also mean, however, that I need to worry that Salesforce will eventually stop supporting Aura components?

Comment: Unless you happen to get an answer from an official Salesforce source, any answers here will be conjecture or opinion. In my opinion Aura will eventually go away but it will be a very long time (since LWC doesn't yet have feature parity and Salesforce hasn't even started end of life for Visualforce, which is now two generations old).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use LWC when possible, as it is much faster performance-wise, and easier to develop, than Aura. However, Aura is the underlying runtime, and it provides core features that won't be in LWC. Namely, it provides the top-level container framework (Lightning Apps) that LWC wasn't designed for.

Even if every component in Salesforce was LWC, it'd still need a container to run in, and Aura serves that purpose perfectly well. If you look at [LWC OSS](https://lwc.dev/), you'll notice that there's still a container, a top-level index.html that needs to be present in order to load LWCs.

So, until/unless there comes a replacement in the future, Aura is assuredly safe from deprecation for the time being. However, if you want a snappy user interface, you'd do well to stop developing new Aura components and go with LWC.

Answer (score 0):

I think both LWC and Lightning Components/Aura Components are based on the JavaScript framework, although as you stated LWC is clearly preferred over Aura.
You need to understand that there are certain things that are present in Lightning components that are not yet present in the Lightning web components.

Even in the article, you have stated you can see that there are certain interfaces, components, events, and tags that are not yet supported or do not have an equivalent replacement in LWC.